# Allow sorting of Area 51 proposals by followers

Tags: feature-request, area-51, sorting, definition-phase, followers

On Area 51 sometimes I want to find sites that have large amounts of people interested but are having trouble getting off the ground by finding good definition questions. I can just look through the list when sorted by progress, but many sites <50 followers have no trouble defining themselves and get ranked above sites with 100+ followers.

Ideally site with large potential user bases should go into beta as soon as possible. Allowing us to sort by followers to find proposals having trouble in definition would definitely help us in this goal (it might also help if this excluded sites already in the commitment phase).